# Move price text over thumbnail to below it when using CSS & Literal Control

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I had this CSS written for me as I'm still learning. It is used to place a price over thumbnails which are displayed using a complicated 'Literal'. It's the end of this long line of code which displays the price using filenameAndPrice(4).....

```
Dim liByLiteral As New LiteralControl("<a href='https://example.com/item.aspx?returnpage=stall&oID=" & friendlyOrderID & "&page=" & page & "&itemCat=" & itemCat & "&stallNo=" & stallNo & "&id=" & filenameAndPrice(0) & "' class=""imageThumbnail"" style=""padding:3px;"" rel=""gal" & DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "accountID").ToString & """ title=""" & filenameAndPrice(2) & " - PRICE: £" & filenameAndPrice(4) & """ onclick=""openImage('" & filenameAndPrice(1) & "', '" & txtItem.ClientID & "', '" & filenameAndPrice(0) & "');""><img class='lazy" & opacity & "' data-src='https://example.com/catalog/images/thumbnails/" & filenameAndPrice(0) & "' src='./files/images/loader.png' /><p><span>£" & filenameAndPrice(4) & "</span></p></a>")
```

I now need to alter the code to display the price underneath the photo instead of over it. However, everything I've tried has resulted in the text being hidden behind the images below.

[image: screenshot]

Here's the front end..

```
<div runat="server" id="usersStall">
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul class="stallRow1" id="stallRow1UL" runat="server"></ul>
        </div>
        <div id="stallRow2nd" runat="server">
            <ul id="stallRow2UL" runat="server"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlLoggedIn" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server" placeholder="Select Item Then Message Seller" visible="false" height="22px" style="font-size: 1.8em; text-align: center;" Columns="28" MaxLength="255"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
.imageThumbnail {
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
}

.imageThumbnail img {
    min-width:90px;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.imageThumbnail p {
  position:absolute;
  top:-20px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  transform:translateY(-50%); /* doesn't work in IE9 and older I'm affraid */
  margin:0px;
}


.imageThumbnail P span {
  color: white;
  margin-left:10px;
  font: bold 18px/36px Helvetica,
  Sans-Serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: rgba(115, 160, 77, 0.7);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to know what you "tried." At first blush, I think it's the `position:absolute` and the `top` and `left` properties on `.imageThumbnail p` selector that are causing it to float over the image. The `transform` property also has an impact. But, basically, `position:absolute` causes that `p` element to hover over the image. So, get rid of those first three properties, for sure. You probably want to eliminate the `transform` property, too.

Comment: Easiest way to do these things are not to change the code and run again etc but just right click the price in your browser and choose Inspect Element, then use the STYLES tab on the right to play with the settings, and when you achieved the look you wanted, replicate those settings in code